# Slow HTTPS requests to all websites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, performance, https

We have some weird behavior on a lot of machines here – computers running Windows 10 x64 and Windows 8.1 x64. Using Internet Explorer we face no problems when visiting different websites, but Chrome is very, very slow when trying to access HTTPS websites, and its *all* HTTPS websites, but only in Chrome. We tested on fresh Chrome installs, even without any users logged into it or extensions installed.

The *only* thing in Internet explorer which is slow? The download of Chrome. On one machine I even tried to download Chrome through Ninite, but that was also slow!

I have tried scanning the affected computers with Malwarebytes and Windows Defender, but nothing shows up. In every other way the computers work fine, so I don't expect there to be any viruses or the like. I've tried changing DNS settings, reinstalling network drivers, etc., but nothing helps.

Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT: I would've loved to test out any of the suggestions here, but I'm no longer able to test this out, as i no longer work at the place where the issue were.

Comment: Does this happen for only chrome? Is there any SSL certificate issue? Try to delete Chrome profile folder and restarts Chrome.

Comment: @Biswa - Only chrome or other browsers based on the chromium framework. Deleting the folder does not help, but I'm having a hard to understanding why deleting that folder should fix it, since the browser is freshly installed on the computers.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Clear `%TEMP%`, (2) Disable firewall and antivirus, (3) Try Google public DNS, (4) Delete CRL and OCSP Caches by `certutil -urlcache * delete`. Question: Is the load slow only the first time and the second load in same session is faster ?

Comment: @harrymc I will try out your tips, however 1, 2 and 3 have already been tried. The load is slow always, however a little faster after the first load due to caching. Is it just as slow on all tries if i disable caching.

Comment: Disable your firewall and try again.

Comment: If this is happening on "a lot of machines here", there might be a common cause. Maybe the problem is on your router(s)/modem(s) or ISP. Try to reboot or reset whatever you can.

Comment: You can investigate with chrome://net-internals/#events , filter an https site that's slow and see what's happening

Comment: please in Chrome enable developer tools and switch to network tab. Then open a HTTPS website, you should see a timeline with everything that chrome does, and you should be able to see if the problem is with DNS, network or something else.

Comment: Run Ubuntu from a USB Drive, install chromium and check the result. Chrome does DNS lookups different than the rest of your system, but I don't have a source for that at the moment.

Comment: Could it be a firewall or proxy in the way or a man in the middle trying to inspect the traffic of https?

Comment: You can download `OPERA` browser that is based on `Chromium` as `Chrome` to check if problem is only on `Chrome` on in `Chromium` ! https://www.opera.com/download

Comment: This is a known issue which can be fixed by a Windows Registry change. I don't have the article in front of me now, and I'll try to post an answer as soon as I can find it again.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this recently and it was a Chrome proxy setting. In the Chrome URL field enter `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` to see the current running proxy settings.

**Test Chrome using different proxy setting flags:**

[image: source: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/chrome-command-line-switches]

1. Exit any running-instance of Chrome.
2. Right click on your "Chrome" shortcut.
3. Choose properties.
4. At the end of your "Target:" line individually test with these flags:

   `--no-proxy-server`

   `--proxy-auto-detect`

   `--winhttp-proxy-resolver`
5. Launch Chrome like normal with the
   shortcut.

You can also open powershell and run `netsh winhttp reset proxy` to remove any proxy server settings in Windows. After doing this navigate back to the Chrome proxy URL from earlier and click re-apply settings.

Sources:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/debugging-net-proxy
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags#TOC-Windows
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=953998
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, resetting winsock may help.
This clears all IP related settings, and sets the network adapters to their default configuration.

***PLEASE NOTE THAT ANY STATIC IP'S SET WILL BE CLEARED***

You can run this with the command: netsh winsock reset 
After running the command, restart the PC.

It is said that windows newer than windows 7 messes with the winsock related files causing issues with Chrome/chrome driven browsers.

Hope this helps!